# Connecting to SQL Server results in error "The driver received an unexpected pre-login response"

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, sql-server-2000

I am unable to connect to sql server, getting following error.

exception com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The TCP/IP connection
to the host SSALES, port 1433 has failed. Error: "The driver received an unexpe
cted pre-login response. Verify the connection properties and check that an inst
ance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at th
e port. This driver can be used only with SQL Server 2000 or later.".

**my local Environment:-**

java 5,
sql server enterprise manager version 8,

**RunApp.java**

```
Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"); 
conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://abc;d‌​atabaseName={db};use‌​r=name;password=pass‌​worf;");
Statement stmt=conn.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM testdb.testtabel where active = 'a'");
```

**running through cmd:**

```
set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk5\bin";

javac -classpath "D:\Web Development\ABC\lib\mail-1.4.3.jar;D:\Web Development\ABC\lib\json-simple.jar;D:\Web Development\ABC\lib\sqljdbc.jar;" com\test\RunApp.java

java -classpath "D:\Web Development\ABC\lib\mail-1.4.3.jar;D:\Web Development\ABC\lib\json-simple.jar;D:\Web Development\ABC\lib\sqljdbc.jar;" com.test.RunApp
```

Comment: Hi ..are you sure you have activated On SQL Server the TCP ? ..you have to check it in the tools of SqlServer

Comment: Which version of the SQL Server JDBC driver are you using, you may need to upgrade.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: we are using sql server enterprise manager 8.0 and using java 5 with jdbc 3.0

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi: yes its enabled

Comment: mm sorry i see now ..that your connectionstring looks like don't have the DBNAME

Comment: 1) Your question mentions using Java 6 not 5 (both of which are pretty old, btw), 2) SQL Server enterprise manager is irrelevant from the perspective of Java, it connects to SQL Server, 3) I am asking about the version of the driver, not the version of the JDBC specification.

Comment: @federicoscamuzzi Sorry I forget add there in question but its included already

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: 1) we are using java 5, 3) what driver you are asking about?

Comment: The Microsoft SQL Server JDBC driver has a version number, and it may well be version 3.0 (which is also pretty old), but the way your phrased your comment suggested you were talking about the JDBC version, as JDBC 3.0 is the JDBC specification version associated with Java 5.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: sql server driver version 2000.86.3959.00

Comment: Are you also still using SQL Server 2000?

Comment: Yes, this is very older server, we can't upgrade now. Please help us on finding the solution.

Comment: use jtds, older microsoft drivers weren't good

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is wrong (see [Building the Connection URL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx)), it should be (note the use of an escaped backslash instead of forward slash):

```
"jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;databaseName={db};user=MyUserName;password=MyPassword;"
```

Also make sure that `{db}` is replaced with the actual name of the database.

You are trying to connecting by instance name, and some googling on the error message suggests this error can occur if the instance name is wrong or if the SQL Server Browser service is not running. So you need to have the SQL Server Browser service enabled (it is disabled by default).

Otherwise you will need to remove the instance name from the URL, and instead specify the correct port number in the JDBC url (usually 1433, but it can depend on the configuration: double check).

Comment: conn = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://abc;databaseName={db};user=name;password=passworf;");  this is how my url looks

Comment: @chethan Not according to your question... I suggest you edit your question with the actual information (for example your exception message also doesn't match the information provided in your question nor in this comment).

Comment: Updated the question